# Can´t sell trucks in my vehicle trader program and 1 JUnit error (abstract method missing)

Tags: java

In my program for trading vehicles (cars oder trucks) you can sell single or multiple vehicles and reorder them. A sold car is delivered with 40l gas and a truck with 80l gas. You can  also refill vehicles and fuel.

-Problems: It does not allow me to sell trucks anymore (it used to). When i run the Interactive file and try to sell a truck nothing happens. But with cars it works even though it´s the same code for cars.

Also i get 2 JUnit errors with the JUnit our professor gave us. Here are the errors:

```
public void testParentClass(){
    CarTrader trader1 = passengerCarTrader;
    trader1.checkAvailability(VehicleBrand.AUDI, 1);
    trader1.isSoldVehicleType(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
    trader1.reorderVehicles(VehicleBrand.AUDI, 1);
```

-The method checkAvailability(int, int) is undefined for the type CarTrader
-The method isSoldVehicleType(byte) is undefined for the type CarTrader
-The method reorderVehicles(int, int) is undefined for the type CarTrader

So i think that means the abstract class is not implemented in the Superclass. But how  can I implement it?

public abstract void checkAvailability();
does  not work

Also it says "The type PassengerCarTrader must implement the inheritated abstract method isSoldVehicle, checkAvailabilty, reorderVehicles.

```
public abstract class CarTrader {

    public static final float CAPACITY_DIESEL_LITERS = 350.f;
    public static final float CAPACITY_GAS_LITERS = 180.f;
    public static final int CAPACITY_PASSENGER_CARS = 15;
    public static final int CAPACITY_TRUCKS = 8;


    float gasStockLiters=180.f;
    float dieselStockLiters=250.f;
    int passengerCarsStock=15;
    int trucksStock=8;

    int mANStock=4;
    int scaniaStock=4;
    int audiStock=4;
    int bMWStock=4;
    int opelStock=4;
    int mercedesStock=3;

    public CarTrader(){

    }

    void setGasStockLiters(float gasStockLiters){
        this.gasStockLiters=gasStockLiters;
    }

    void setDieselStockLiters(float dieselStockLiters){
        this.dieselStockLiters=dieselStockLiters;
    }

    void setPassengerCarsStock(int passengerCarsStock){
        this.passengerCarsStock=passengerCarsStock;
    }

    void setTrucksStock(int trucksStock){
        this.trucksStock=trucksStock;
    }

    int getPassengerCarsStock(){
        return passengerCarsStock;
    }

    int getTrucksStock(){
        return trucksStock;
    }
    float getGasStockLiters(){
        return gasStockLiters;
    }
    float getDieselStockLiters(){
        return dieselStockLiters;
    }
    CarTrader(int a){
        this.audiStock=a;
    }


    public Vehicle sellVehicle(byte vehicleType, int brand){

    Vehicle soldCar=null;


    switch (vehicleType){


    case 0: 

        if (this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR){


            switch (brand) {
            case VehicleBrand.AUDI:

                if (this.audiStock>=1){
                    this.audiStock = this.audiStock - 1;
                    this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
                    this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - 1;
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
                } else {

                    System.err.println("Nicht genug AUDI oder Benzin vorhanden");
                }
                break;
            case VehicleBrand.BMW:
                if(this.bMWStock>=1){
                    this.bMWStock = this.bMWStock -1;
                    this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR ;
                    this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - 1;
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Nicht genug BMW oder Benzin vorhanden");
                }
                break;
            case VehicleBrand.MERCEDES:
                if (this.mercedesStock>=1){
                    this.mercedesStock = this.mercedesStock - 1;
                    this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
                    this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - 1;
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Nicht genug Mercedes oder Benzin vorhanden");
                }
                break;
            case VehicleBrand.OPEL:
                if(this.opelStock>=1){
                    this.opelStock = this.opelStock -1;
                    this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
                    this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - 1;
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);

                } else {
                    System.err.println("Nicht genug Opel oder Benzin vorhanden");
                }
                break;
            default: soldCar=null;

            break;
            }
        } else {
        soldCar=null;
        }

            System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft");
    break;

    case VehicleBrand.MAN:

        if (this.dieselStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK){

            switch (brand) {
            case 1://MAN
                if (this.mANStock>=1){
                    this.mANStock = (this.mANStock-1);
                    trucksStock = trucksStock - 1;
                    dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
                    System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft");
                } else {
                    soldCar=null;
                    System.err.println("Nicht genug MAN-Trucks oder Diesel vorhanden");

                }
                break;
            case VehicleBrand.SCANIA:
                if(this.scaniaStock>=1){
                    this.scaniaStock = this.scaniaStock -1;
                    trucksStock = trucksStock - 1;
                    dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;
                    System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft");
                    soldCar = new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
                } else {
                    soldCar=null;
                    System.err.println("Nicht genug Scania-Trucks oder Diesel vorhanden");

                }
                break;
            default: soldCar=null;
            }

            break;
            }
        else {
            soldCar=null;
        }
    }
        return soldCar;
    }








    public Vehicle[] sellVehicles(byte vehicleType, int brand, int amount){

    Vehicle[] soldCar= new Vehicle[amount];
        boolean sold=false;

        switch (vehicleType){
        case 0:

            if(this.dieselStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK*amount){

                switch (brand) {
                case VehicleBrand.MAN://MAN
                    if (this.mANStock>=amount){
                        this.mANStock = this.mANStock - amount;
                        trucksStock = trucksStock - amount;
                        dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK*amount;
                        sold=true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Nicht genug MAN-Trucks oder Diesel vorhanden");
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleBrand.SCANIA://Scania
                    if(this.scaniaStock>=amount){
                        this.scaniaStock = this.scaniaStock -amount;
                        trucksStock = trucksStock - amount;
                        dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK*amount;
                        sold=true;
                        } else {
                            System.err.println("Nicht genug Scania-Trucks oder Diesel vorhanden");
                    }
                    if (sold=true){
                        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
                            soldCar[i]=new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
                        }

                        System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft"); 
                    }
                    if (sold=false) {
                        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
                        soldCar[i]=null;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }


        case 1:

            if (this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR*amount){


                switch (brand){
                case VehicleBrand.AUDI://AUDI
                    if (this.audiStock>=amount){
                        this.audiStock = this.audiStock - amount;
                        this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR*amount;
                        this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - amount;
                        sold=true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Nicht genug AUDI oder Benzin vorhanden");
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleBrand.BMW://BMW
                    if(this.bMWStock>=amount){
                        this.bMWStock = this.bMWStock -amount;
                        this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR*amount;
                        this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - amount;
                        sold=true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Nicht genug BMW oder Benzin vorhanden");
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleBrand.MERCEDES://MERCEDES
                    if (this.mercedesStock>=amount){
                        this.mercedesStock = this.mercedesStock - amount;
                        this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR*amount;
                        this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - amount;
                        sold=true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Nicht genug Mercedes oder Benzin vorhanden");
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleBrand.OPEL://OPEL
                    if(this.opelStock>=amount){
                        this.opelStock = this.opelStock -amount;
                        this.gasStockLiters = this.gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR *amount;
                        this.passengerCarsStock = this.passengerCarsStock - amount;
                        sold=true;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Nicht genug Opel oder Benzin vorhanden");
                    }
                    break;
                }       
                    if (sold=true){
                        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
                            soldCar[i]=new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
                        }
                    System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft"); 
                    }
                    if (sold=false) {
                        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
                        soldCar[i]=null;
                        }
             }
           }
        }
                return soldCar;


    }

    public boolean fillGas(float gas){

        boolean filled=false;

        if((gasStockLiters + gas)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_GAS_LITERS){

            gasStockLiters = gasStockLiters + gas;
            filled=true;
        }
            else{
                System.err.println("Die Kapazität beträgt höchstens 180 Liter");
            }
        return filled;
        }

    public boolean fillDiesel(float diesel){

        boolean  filled2=false;

        if((dieselStockLiters + diesel)<=CarTrader.CAPACITY_DIESEL_LITERS){

            dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters + diesel; 
            filled2=true;
        }

            else{
                System.err.println("Die Kapazität beträgt höchstens 250 Liter");
            }
        return filled2;
    }


     public abstract void isSoldVehicle();

    void statusOutput()
    {
        System.out.println("AutoHändler - Lagerbestand:");
        System.out.println("    PKW: " + passengerCarsStock);
        System.out.println("Audi: " +this.audiStock);
        System.out.println("BMW: "+ this.bMWStock);
        System.out.println("Mercedes: "+ this.mercedesStock);
        System.out.println("Opel: "+ this.opelStock);
        System.out.println("LKWHändler - Lagerbestand");
        System.out.println("    LKW: " + trucksStock);
        System.out.println("MAN: "+ this.mANStock);
        System.out.println("Scania "+this.scaniaStock);
        System.out.println("Kraftstoff Lagerbestand:");
        System.out.println("    - Diesel: " + dieselStockLiters);
        System.out.println("    - Benzin: " + gasStockLiters);
    }
}

PassengerCarTrader 

    public class PassengerCarTrader extends CarTrader {





        public static final int CAPACITY_AUDI = 4;
        public static final int CAPACITY_BMW = 4;
        public static final int CAPACITY_OPEL = 4;
        public static final int CAPACITY_MERCEDES = 3;


            void setGasStockLiters(float gasStockLiters){
                this.gasStockLiters=gasStockLiters;
            }
            void setPassengerCarsStock(int passengerCarsStock){
                this.passengerCarsStock=passengerCarsStock;
            }

            int getPassengerCarsStock(){
                return passengerCarsStock;
            }

            float getGasStockLiters(){
                return gasStockLiters;
            }
            void setMercedesStock(int mercedesStock){
                this.mercedesStock=mercedesStock;
            }
            void setBMWStock(int bMWStock){
                this.bMWStock=bMWStock;
            }
            void setAudiStock(int audistock){
                this.audiStock=audistock;
            }
            void setOpelStock(int opelstock){
                this.opelStock=opelstock;
            }
            int getMercedesStock(){
                return mercedesStock;
            }
            int getBMWStock(){
                return bMWStock;
            }
            int getOpelStock(){
                return opelStock;
            }
            int getAudiStock(){
                return audiStock;
            }



            public boolean reorderVehicles(int amountVehicles, int brand){

                boolean full=false;

                if((passengerCarsStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_PASSENGER_CARS){

                    switch (brand){
                    case VehicleBrand.AUDI: 
                        if ((this.audiStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_AUDI){
                            this.audiStock += amountVehicles;
                        }
                        break;
                    case VehicleBrand.BMW:
                        if((this.bMWStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_BMW){
                            this.bMWStock += amountVehicles;
                        }
                        break;
                    case VehicleBrand.MERCEDES:
                        if((this.mercedesStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_MERCEDES){
                            this.mercedesStock += amountVehicles;
                        }
                        break;
                    case VehicleBrand.OPEL:
                        if((this.opelStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_OPEL){
                            this.opelStock += amountVehicles;
                        }
                        break;
                    default: 
                        System.err.println("Ungültige Eingabe");

                        break;
                    }
                    passengerCarsStock += amountVehicles;
                    full=true;
                }
                return full;
            }

            public void isSoldVehicleType(byte type){
                if (type==VehicleType.TRUCK){
                    System.out.println("Es handelt sich um einen Truck");
                }
                if (type==VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){
                    System.out.println("Es handelt sich um einen PKW");
                }
            }

            public boolean checkAvailability (int brand, int amount){

                boolean available=false;

                switch (brand){
                case VehicleBrand.AUDI: if(this.audiStock>=amount){
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                    available=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
                }
                case VehicleBrand.BMW: if(this.bMWStock>=amount){
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                    available=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
                }
                case VehicleBrand.MERCEDES: if(this.mercedesStock>=amount){
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                    available=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
                }
                case VehicleBrand.OPEL: if(this.opelStock>=amount){
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                    available=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
                }
                default:
                    System.err.println("Bitte wählen Sie 1 bis 4");
                }
                return available;
            }
    }

TruckTrader

    public class TruckTrader extends CarTrader{

    public static final int CAPACITY_MAN = 4;
    public static final int CAPACITY_SCANIA = 4;




     void setDieselStockLiters(int dieselStockLiters){
         this.dieselStockLiters=dieselStockLiters;
     }
     void setTrucksStock(int trucksStock){
         this.trucksStock=trucksStock;
     }
     void setMANStock(int mANStock){
         this.mANStock=mANStock;
     }
     void setScaniaStock(int scaniaStock){
         this.scaniaStock=scaniaStock;
     }
     float getDieselStockLiters(){
         return dieselStockLiters;
     }
     int getTrucksStock(){
         return trucksStock;
     }

     int getMANStock(){
         return mANStock;
     }
     int getScaniaStock(){
         return scaniaStock;
     }


     public boolean reorderVehicles(int amountVehicles, int brand){

            boolean full=false;

            if((trucksStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_TRUCKS){

                switch (brand){
                case VehicleBrand.MAN: 
                    if ((this.mANStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_MAN){
                        this.mANStock += amountVehicles;
                    }
                    break;
                case VehicleBrand.SCANIA:
                    if((this.scaniaStock+amountVehicles)<=CAPACITY_SCANIA){
                        this.scaniaStock += amountVehicles;
                    }
                    break;

                default: 
                    System.err.println("Ungültige Eingabe");
                    break;
                }
                trucksStock += amountVehicles;
                full=true;
            }
            return full;
        }

     public void isSoldVehicleType(byte type){
            if (type==VehicleType.TRUCK){
                System.out.println("Es handelt sich um einen Truck");
            }
            if (type==VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){
                System.out.println("Es handelt sich um einen PKW");
            }
        }

     public boolean checkAvailability (int brand, int amount){

            boolean available=false;

            switch (brand){
            case VehicleBrand.MAN: if(this.mANStock>=amount){
                System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                available=true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
            }
            case VehicleBrand.SCANIA: if(this.scaniaStock>=amount){
                System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist verfügbar");
                available=true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Die gewünschte Menge ist nicht verfügbar");
            }

            }
            return available;
        }


}

VehicleBrand

    public final class VehicleBrand {

    public static final int AUDI = 1;
    public static final int BMW = 2;
    public static final int OPEL = 3;
    public static final int MERCEDES = 4;

    public static final int MAN = 1;
    public static final int SCANIA = 2;

     //This class is just an organizer for the above constants; Not instantiable.

    private VehicleBrand(){
    }
}

VehicleType

    public final class VehicleType {

    public static final byte PASSENGER_CAR = 7;

    public static final byte TRUCK = 5;


    /**
     * This class is just an organizer for the above constants; Not instantiable.
     */
    private VehicleType(){

    }

}

Vehicle

    public class Vehicle {
    public static final float TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR = 40.f;
    public static final float TANK_SIZE_TRUCK = 80.f;
    public float fuel;
    public byte mVehicleType;
    public int brand;

    public Vehicle(){}

    public Vehicle(byte vehicleType){
        this();
        if (vehicleType == VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR){
            this.mVehicleType= VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR ;
            this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;

        }

        if(vehicleType == VehicleType.TRUCK){
            this.mVehicleType= VehicleType.TRUCK;
            this.fuel= Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;

        }
    }

    public float getFuel(){
        return this.fuel;
    }

    public byte getVehicleType(){
        return this.mVehicleType;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It does not allow me to sell trucks anymore (it used to)."* It used be before what?

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code until you have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem? This will increase your chances of getting good answers by a lot!

Comment: Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please make sure your [code is properly marked/indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262).  Also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to write good questions. This will increase your chances of someone actually answering your question a great deal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the child classes have a method that looks like:

```
public boolean checkAvailability(int brand, int amount) {
    // .....
}
```

And if you want to use variables of the parent class and have them call this method, then the parent abstract class must also declare this method.  It can be an abstract method since the child classes have already implemented it, but it must be present, and also understand that this is not adequate:

```
public abstract void checkAvailability();
```

since the method signatures must match *exactly*, including the return type and parameters. You must have something like this in your parent class:

```
public abstract boolean checkAvailability(int brand, int amount);
```

Do you see the difference, including the return type and the parameters? Your compiler is strict and unforgiving, and so you the coder must be as well.

After you've done this, add above your child class an `@Override` annotation to make sure that the overrides are done correctly.

---

Also this:

```
CarTrader trader1 = passengerCarTrader;
```

won't compile. It needs to be something more like:

```
CarTrader trader1 = New PassengerCarTrader();
```

Again, your compiler will not forgive sloppiness, and so you must strive to avoid it both in your coding and in your questions here.

---

In the future, please try to simplify your code and your problem to the bare minimum to demonstrate your problem. For this problem, all you'd need would be something like:

```
public class TestCars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarTrader trader1 = new PassengerCarTrader();
        if (trader1.checkAvailability(3, 1));
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class CarTrader {
    public abstract void checkAvailability(); 
}
```

```
public class PassengerCarTrader extends CarTrader {
    public boolean checkAvailability(int brand, int amount) {
        boolean availability = false;
        // .....

        return availability;
    }
}
```

which obviously doesn't compile, while this does:

```
public class TestCars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarTrader trader1 = new PassengerCarTrader();
        if (trader1.checkAvailability(3, 1));
    }
}
```

```
abstract class CarTrader {
    public abstract boolean checkAvailability(int brand, int amount); 
}
```

```
class PassengerCarTrader extends CarTrader {
    @Override
    public boolean checkAvailability(int brand, int amount) {
        boolean availability = false;
        // .....

        return availability;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobinPe: you're welcome, but more importantly 1) do you see why your attempt wasn't working and 2) in the future, please pare your code down to the minimum needed to reproduce your problem -- please see my edited answer above to see what I mean. You've posted **way** too much code that has nothing to do with your problem and only served to confuse and delay your getting an answer.